# Facebook SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, curl

I am trying to connect with Facebook For Login, but I do not know why I am getting errors. Below is the curl code that I am using:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().'/cacert.pem');    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");        
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

but still I am getting below error :

```
error: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

My server is Centos 6.5 with PHP 5.4 with below Curl Version :

> curl 7.44.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.44.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e  zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.10.0 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.6.0
>
> Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>
> Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets Metalink

Comment: Might probably b due to this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/06/02/SHA-2-Updates-Needed/

Comment: As i remove SSL3 Option, then i get this         error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.facebook.com:443

Comment: You need to use TLS 1.2